# Adding a Point in LinkedList without overwriting another Point - Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to insert the value (10,10) at the index 1 of the LinkedList ar. I want the value (1,1) to move on node to make space for the (10,10). What is the fastest way of doing that? Can I use different data structure to get better results?

```
    LinkedList<Point> ar = new LinkedList<Point>();
    ar.add(new Point(0,0));
    ar.add(new Point(1,1));
    ar.add(new Point(2,2));
    ar.set(1,new Point(10,10));
    for (int i=0;i<3; i++){
    System.out.println(ar.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen the overloaded `add` method?

Comment: Answer made a community wiki since it is a dup as per @SotiriosDelimanolis. Thus anyone can edit/improve the answer, and no one gets points for up-votes.

Answer (score 2):

The `set(...)` method replaces items. You should instead use the `add(int index, Object o)` overload method to insert an item at a specific index and not replace.

The price of using this method with a `LinkedList` depends on how far you need to iterate to get to your target destination. With an `ArrayList` the price is potentially creating a bigger backing array and shifting all elements in indices after your target. (Always check with the corresponding `List` implementation.)